# Finding all a to have atleast one real root

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Find all $a \in \Bbb R$ for which $$(1 + a) \left(\frac{x^2}{1 + x^2}\right)^2 - 3a\left(\frac{x^2}{1 + x^2}\right) + 4a = 0$$ has at least one real root.

For this problem, I tried substituting $y = x^2 / 1 + x^2$ and then arrived at the quadratic $$(1+a)y^2 - 3ay + 4a = 0$$ then the discriminant $$\Delta = 9a^2 - 4(1+a)(4a) = 9a^2 - 16a - 16 a^2 = -7a^2 - 16a$$ Now setting the discriminant $\geq 0$ since we need real roots gives $$-\frac{16}{7}\le\:a\le\:0$$.

However, I am confident this is an **incorrect** way since this considers the quadratic and not the original equation (??). I do not have access to the solution/answers so I am a bit lost on this.
So what is the correct approach for this? Any hints will suffice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that

1. $\frac{x^2}{1 + x^2}$ takes values in $[0, 1)$.
2. $\frac{x^2}{1 + x^2}$ takes **all** values in $[0, 1)$.

Thus, your original equation (in $x$) has *a* real solution iff your transformed equation (in $y$) has *a* solution in $[0, 1)$. (Note that the equation in $y$ may have two real solutions with only one being in $[0, 1)$, that is OK.)

What you have done will only ensure that the transformed equation has root(s) in $\Bbb R$. That is not enough.

Firstly note that if $a = -1$, then you have a linear equation and you can note that case simply.

Now, assume that $a \neq -1$. You can explicitly solve the quadratic in $y$ and impose the condition that one of the roots lies in $[0, 1)$. (As a first step, you must have that both roots are real. You have already shown that this restricts $a$ to be in $[-16/7, 0]$.)

Answer (score 2):

Why to make the problem more complex than it is ?

Since, in the real domain, $(1+x^2) >0$, multiply everything by $(1+x^2)^2$ to end with
$$(1+2a)x^4+5ax^2+4a=0$$ which is a quadratic in $x^2$. So, you know the condition for real roots in $x^2$ and at leat one of these roots must be non-negative.

Comment: I don't know if I really prefer this. This looks smart but when I substitute $x^2$ to make it a proper quadratic and take the discriminant but then I have to relate back to the original equation I get stuck. And when I put that biquadratic equation in wolfram I get a completely different disriminant.

I don't understand biquadratics that well.
I will figure something out eventually...